# Modem manager in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: modem-manager

I am using mc509 in a Ubuntu 14.04  box.

```
uname -a;lsb_release -a

Linux HBOX-0100b5 3.10.17 #1 SMP Wed Sep 3 02:38:52 PDT 2014 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

The module is detected correct and using the correct driver.

```
lsusb;usb-devices
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 12d1:1404 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2412 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 1
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.10
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.10.17 ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=ci_hdrc.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0424 ProdID=2412 Rev=0b.b2
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=2mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 1
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.10
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.10.17 ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=ci_hdrc.1
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1404 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=HUAÃ¿WEI TECHNOLOGIES
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
S:  SerialNumber=Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿
C:  #Ifs= 5 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option.
ls -al /dev/serial/by-id
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 140 Sep 12 17:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  80 Sep 12 17:31 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Sep 12 17:31 usb-HUA??WEI_TECHNOLOGIES_HUAWEI_Mobile-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Sep 12 17:31 usb-HUA??WEI_TECHNOLOGIES_HUAWEI_Mobile-if01-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Sep 12 17:31 usb-HUA??WEI_TECHNOLOGIES_HUAWEI_Mobile-if02-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Sep 12 17:31 usb-HUA??WEI_TECHNOLOGIES_HUAWEI_Mobile-if03-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Sep 12 17:31 usb-HUA??WEI_TECHNOLOGIES_HUAWEI_Mobile-if04-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB4
```

Using wv dial I am able connect to the network. I have a need to use the Modem manager and dbus  modem-manager interface.I am a novice using modem manager.  This is how I configured modem manager.

```
mmcli -L

Found 1 modems:
        /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.] MC509

mmcli -m 0

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 (device id '465738ce82d321b55ab1d1890635105d5429fca6')
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.'
           |          model: 'MC509'
           |       revision: '11.106.19.03.322'
           |      supported: 'cdma-evdo'
           |        current: 'cdma-evdo'
           |   equipment id: '8001bf7e'
  -------------------------
  System   |         device: '/sys/devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1'
           |        drivers: 'option1'
           |         plugin: 'Huawei'
           |   primary port: 'ttyUSB2'
           |          ports: 'ttyUSB0 (at), ttyUSB1 (qcdm), ttyUSB2 (at), ttyUSB4 (at)'
  -------------------------
  Numbers  |           own : '8508193144'
  -------------------------
  Status   |           lock: 'none'
           | unlock retries: 'unknown'
           |          state: 'connected'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'evdoa'
           | signal quality: '40' (recent)
  -------------------------
  Modes    |      supported: 'allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none'
           |        current: 'allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g'
  -------------------------
  Bands    |      supported: 'unknown'
           |        current: 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  IP       |      supported: 'ipv4'
  -------------------------
  CDMA     |           meid: 'unknown'
           |            esn: '8001bf7e'
           |            sid: 'unknown'
           |            nid: 'unknown'
           |   registration: CDMA1x 'unknown'
           |                 EV-DO  'home'
           |     activation: 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  SIM      |           path: 'none'
```

`mmcli -m 0  --simple-connect="user='',password='',number=#777"` says successfully connected but I don’t see any ppp interface listed in ifconfig

```
mmcli -m 0 --simple-status

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
  -------------------------
  Status |          state: 'connected'
         | signal quality: '40' (recent)
         |          bands: 'unknown'
         |    access tech: 'evdoa'
  -------------------------
  CDMA   |            sid: 'unknown'
         |            nid: 'unknown'
         |   registration: CDMA1x 'unknown'
         |                 EV-DO  'home'

ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:b8:f6:01:00:f5
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:105367 (105.3 KB)  TX bytes:16454 (16.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:592 (592.0 B)  TX bytes:592 (592.0 B)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:33:14:4d:a1:34
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Here is ModemManager logs from /var/log/syslog.

```
grep -i modem /var/log/syslog
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: option 2-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: option 2-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: option 2-1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: option 2-1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: option 2-1:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Sep 12 20:10:26 localhost kernel: usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
Sep 12 20:10:33 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.0.0) starting...
Sep 12 20:10:33 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:33 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB1): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:33 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:33 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB3): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:33 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB4): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:36 localhost NetworkManager[992]: <info> ModemManager available in the bus
Sep 12 20:10:36 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB1): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:36 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:36 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB3): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:36 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB4): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:54 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Creating modem with plugin 'Huawei' and '5' ports
Sep 12 20:10:54 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyUSB3): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB3', unhandled serial type'
Sep 12 20:10:54 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:10:54 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Modem for device at '/sys/devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1' successfully created
Sep 12 20:10:54 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  Couldn't load unlock retries: 'SIM not inserted'
Sep 12 20:10:54 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  couldn't load current Bands: 'Couldn't build bands array from '7''
Sep 12 20:10:54 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Modem: state changed (unknown -> disabled)
Sep 12 20:11:15 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Simple connect started...
Sep 12 20:11:15 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Simple connect state (3/8): Enable
Sep 12 20:11:15 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disabled -> enabling)
Sep 12 20:11:15 localhost NetworkManager[992]: <info> (ttyUSB2) modem state changed, 'disabled' --> 'enabling' (reason: user-requested)
Sep 12 20:11:15 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:11:15 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB4): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (enabling -> registered)
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost NetworkManager[992]: <info> (ttyUSB2) modem state changed, 'enabling' --> 'registered' (reason: user-requested)
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (40)
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: access technology changed (unknown -> evdoa)
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Simple connect state (7/8): Connect
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (registered -> connecting)
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost NetworkManager[992]: <info> (ttyUSB2) modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
Sep 12 20:11:16 localhost ModemManager[944]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
Sep 12 20:11:18 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connecting -> connected)
Sep 12 20:11:18 localhost NetworkManager[992]: <info> (ttyUSB2) modem state changed, 'connecting' --> 'connected' (reason: user-requested)
Sep 12 20:11:18 localhost ModemManager[944]: <info>  Simple connect state (8/8): All done.
```

Comment: Are you sure it is Ubuntu? AFAIK, there was no release with 3.10.17.